# How to check if the ribbon is showing in sharepoint 2013 in javascript?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, publishing-site

In pages in SP 2013, they can be in two states, either the ribbon is hidden or its showing. You can change this by doing site actions > show ribbon/hide ribbon. How can I check this state in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

When the ribbon is hidden `CUI` and `SP.Ribbon` are `undefined`. So the easiest way I can think of is to check whether this is the case or not.

e.g.:

```
if (typeof CUI == 'undefined') {
  console.log('ribbon is hidden')
} else {
  console.log('ribbon is visible')
}
```

And if you want to check immediately after the page loaded you can push a function into the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames`-array. It will be executed after all other scripts are loaded and if `CUI` and/or `SP.Ribbon` are still not there then the ribbon must be hidden.

```
function runAfterEverythingElse(){
    if (typeof CUI == 'undefined') {
      console.log('ribbon is hidden')
    } else {
      console.log('ribbon is visible')
    }
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");
```